# Fast train between Moscow and Saint Petersburg?

Tags: trains, russia, high-speed-rail, moscow, saint-petersburg

I'm planning to go on holiday to Moscow Russia in April and would really like to see Saint Petersburg as well.

I've heard that there's a speed train which travels between the two cities, does anyone know how long is the journey and how often do these trains run(once,twice a day etc)

Comment: ICE3-like if you have driven before

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's called SAPSAN, there are 7 trains in both directions *Saint-Petersburg > Moscow* and *Moscow > Saint-Petersburg*.

Here is link to [schedules](http://sapsan.su/schedule.htm) ([Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://sapsan.su/schedule.htm))

Prices are [here](http://sapsan.su/tariffs.htm) ([translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsapsan.su%2Ftariffs.htm)). There are business and economy class tickets available.

The average journey is no longer than 4 hours in one direction.
All trains serve every day except train 154 (runs only on Mondays and Saturdays).

Comment: It seems that sapsan.su is not an official ticket provider and has accrued a lot of bad rap from people who tried using it (see e.g. [#1](http://dmirix.ru/society/rzhd-ya-v-beshenstve/) and [#2](http://otzovik.com/review_745913.html)). It should be safer and easier to buy all railway tickets from the [official RZD's website](https://pass.rzd.ru/main-pass/public/en).

Answer (score 5):

As Volodymyr mentioned, the train is called *Sapsan*, Russian for *peregrine falcon*. It is a Siemens-built high-speed train based on the ICE 3 running in Germany and Siemens calls it *Velaro RUS*. Some also serve the Moscow–Nizhnyi Novgorod relation.

You can use the site of [Russian Railways](http://pass.rzd.ru/main-pass/public/en) to search for departure times and travel times. Look for the *САПСАН* text below the train number to identify them. Note that the departure times are *not* spread out across the day. Rather, there is a ‘morning cluster’, an ‘evening cluster’ and on some days, a ‘lunchtime cluster’. The journey time varies between 3:40 h and 4:05 h, probably depending on the number of stops on the way (didn’t check to confirm the hypothesis).

To board, be there *timely* at Moscow Leningradsky station, be prepared to have your luggage screened as if boarding a flight, and then present passport and ticket to the conductors when boarding as is the norm for Russian long-distance trains.

The train ride itself was very pleasant (I travelled with the cheapest option possible in late summer 2015) and a small meal was included (a sandwich or so if I remember correctly).

Comment: SPb-NN Sapsan runs once again AFAIK.

Comment: @alamar St. Petersburg–Nizhnyi Novgorod? Not Moscow–NN?

Comment: it's SPb - Moscow - NN @ 8H.

Comment: @alamar Ah, thanks, I was under the impression that they would be two different routes i.e. certain trains running eastwards and others northwestwards from Moscow!

Comment: there were plenty of fast trains between Moscow and NN even without Sapsan, such as aforementioned Talgo/Стриж.

Comment: @alamar Yes, of course, but I tried only talking about the Sapsan in this answer (but supplying a reason for why it was withdrawn from that one route — a reason I heard in Russia).

Comment: In the past there were Moscow-NN sapsans and SPb-Moscow-NN sapsans, now that they are restarted there are only latter (and SPb-Moscow of course).

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Nevskij Express](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5248&layer_id=3290&id=2298).

It is more like classic Russian/European trains, cars of compartments with actual doors and 6 seats per compartment. I would argue there's more personal space. Ticket price is usually comparable to Sapsan. Departure time is not very convenient (it's a day train) but it's in demand. It takes `4:05h` without any stops.